# A geometry element of a collision file could not be created

Tags: gazebo, ros2, husky, ros-humble, gazebo-ignition

I'm trying to use the Husky robot from the fuel store, but one specific element from the collision file could not be created, does anyone know how to fix this? I've tried loading this in my own and empty worlds and the error remains the same. I use ROS2 Humble and gazebo garden.

This is the error message:
[gz-1] [Err] [SDFFeatures.cc:843] The geometry element of collision [base_link_fixed_joint_lump__top_plate_link_collision_3] couldn't be created

And this is the link to the model I'v tried to use:
https://app.gazebosim.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/COSTAR_HUSKY_SENSOR_CONFIG_1

Comment: I also have that error message pop up frequently, even though the collisions in my simulation work just fine. So I think that it is (always? often?) a stale error message. In other words: do you experience an actual issue with collisions in your simulation, or are you just concerned about the error message?

Comment: @JRTG I don't experience any issues with collisions either, but I was wondering if there was something wrong in my simulation that caused the message. Maybe you're right and this message always shows. Thanks for the reply